# Laravel 5 Pagination undefined variable vehicles in view

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5

I am trying to use L5 pagination, everything looks fine until i click to second page link. When i click it i am getting this error:

> Laravel 5 Pagination undefined variable vehicles in view

Controller

```
public function search() {
    $vehicle = Vehicle::with('representive','seller','buyer','whoUpdated')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();;

    $previous = Vehicle::where('id', '<', $vehicle->id)->max('id');

    $next = Vehicle::where('id', '>', $vehicle->id)->min('id');

    $first = Vehicle::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->first();
    $last = Vehicle::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();


    //passing rapyd components
    $rapydProcess = new RapydController();
    $searchFilter = $rapydProcess->createSearchFilter();
    $searchGrid = $rapydProcess->createVehicleDataGrid($searchFilter);
    $vehicleTrackFilter = $rapydProcess->createVehicleTrackFilter();
    $vehicleTrackDataGrid = $rapydProcess->createVehicleTrackDataGrid($vehicleTrackFilter);
    //$statisticsDataGrid = $rapydProcess->statisticsDataGrid();

    //passing select box contents to view
    $clients = Client::lists('full_name', 'id');
    $vehicleTypes = VehicleType::lists('vehicle_type', 'id');
    $sections = Section::lists('section_name', 'id');
    $brands = Brand::lists('brand_name', 'id');
    $paymentTypes = PaymentType::lists('payment_type', 'id');
    $searchOptions = StatisticsSearchOptions::lists('option_name', 'slug');

    $option1 = Request::get('option1');
    $option2 = Request::get('option2');
    $condition = Request::get('condition');
    $date_option = Request::get('dateOption');
    $option1_value = Request::get('option1_value');
    $option2_value = Request::get('option2_value');
    $fromDate = Request::get('fromDate');
    $toDate = Request::get('toDate');

    if (isset($option1_value)) {
        $actual_option1 = '';
        foreach ($option1_value as $value) {
            if ($value != '') {
                $actual_option1 = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    if (isset($option1_value)) {
        $actual_option2 = '';
        foreach ($option2_value as $value) {
            if ($value != '') {
                $actual_option2 = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    if($condition == 'no'){
        $vehicles = Vehicle::with('brand','section','representive','buyer','seller','buyingPaymentType','sellingPaymentType')->where($option1, $actual_option1)->paginate(2);
        //return $vehicle;
    }
    if($condition == 'or'){
        $vehicles = Vehicle::with('brand','section','representive','buyer','seller','buyingPaymentType','sellingPaymentType')->where($option1, $actual_option1)->orWhere($option2, $actual_option2)->paginate(2);
    }
    if($condition == 'and'){
        $vehicles = Vehicle::with('brand','section','representive','buyer','seller','buyingPaymentType','sellingPaymentType')->where($option1, $actual_option1)->where($option2, $actual_option2)->paginate(2);
    }

    return view('pages.aracislemler', compact('vehicles','condition','option1','option2','actual_option1','actual_option2','vehicle','previous','next','first','last','searchFilter', 'searchGrid', 'vehicleTrackFilter', 'vehicleTrackDataGrid', 'statisticsDataGrid', 'vehicleTypes', 'sections', 'brands', 'clients','paymentTypes','searchOptions'));
    //return $vehicles;
}
```

View

```
@if(isset($vehicles))
    @foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 15px;">{{ $vehicle->id }}</td>
            <td style="padding: 15px;">{{ $vehicle->brand_id }}</td>
            <td style="padding: 15px;">{{ $vehicle->model }}</td>
            <td style="padding: 15px;">{{ $vehicle->type_id }}</td>
            <td style="padding: 15px;">{{ $vehicle->licenseplate }}</td>
            <td style="padding: 15px;">{{ $vehicle->representive_client_id }}</td>
            <td style="padding: 15px;">{{ $vehicle->buyer_client_id }}</td>
            <td style="padding: 15px;">{{ $vehicle->seller_client_id }}</td>
            <td style="padding: 15px;">{{ $vehicle->debit_situation }}</td>
            <td style="padding: 15px;">{{ $vehicle->partner_situation }}</td>
            <td style="padding: 15px;"><a href="{{ URL::to( 'pages/vehicles?show=' . $vehicle -> id ) }}">Git</a></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif

{!! $vehicles->appends(['condition' => 'condition','option1' => 'option1','option2' => 'option2','actual_option1' => 'actual_option1','actual_option2' => 'actual_option2'])->render()!!}
```

As a L5 newbie i do not know what to do about it, how can i fix this problem ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not appending your `$condition` to the pagination, so it is lost. In the `if` statements before returning the View (in the Controller), you only set the `$vehicles` variable when a `$condition` is met (there is no fallback), so it will not pass on the `$vehicles` to the view. It would be wise to set a fallback, in case there actually is no condition, set the `$vehicles` variable to something, otherwise it will cause the error you are having.

Note that you also have to pass it on to your view! (you are not currently doing that)

Try something like this in your View:

```
{!! $vehicles->appends(['condition' => $condition])->render()!!}
```

And add it to your Controller:

```
return view('pages.aracislemler', compact('vehicles', 'condition'...
```

source: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination (search for appending)

Edit (as discussed in comments and as @HieuLu explained too: (Example, you might have to change the last `else` to your needs)

```
if($condition == 'no'){
    $vehicles = Vehicle::with('brand','section','representive','buyer','seller','buyingPaymentType','sellingPaymentType')->where($option1, $actual_option1)->paginate(2);
    //return $vehicle;
}
elseif($condition == 'or'){
    $vehicles =             Vehicle::with('brand','section','representive','buyer','seller','buyingPaymentType','sellingPaymentType')->where($option1, $actual_option1)->orWhere($option2, $actual_option2)->paginate(2);
}
elseif($condition == 'and'){
    $vehicles = Vehicle::with('brand','section','representive','buyer','seller','buyingPaymentType','sellingPaymentType')->where($option1, $actual_option1)->where($option2, $actual_option2)->paginate(2);
} 
else {
    $vehicles = Vehicle::with('brand','section','representive','buyer','seller','buyingPaymentType','sellingPaymentType')->paginate(2);
}
```

Comment: Still having the same problem

Comment: Perhaps try to add all variables you need to the appends?

Comment: What else do i need except condition ?

Comment: Not sure, are you getting an error now? I'm not sure if all the other values that it uses in the condition (option1, option2.. etc) are empty now. Could you var_dump() or dd() vehicles perhaps to debug. What exactly is going wrong now?

Comment: I have returned and appened all these values still getting undefined vehicles error

Comment: yeah, $vehicles still isn't set when you return like @HieuLu explained a bit more clearly. You should add .. I'll update my answer, but I think that still does not work for you?

Comment: My updated questions still does not work, is that what you mean ?

Comment: Yes I see no change, is it about the same as I have in my updated answer above? :)

Comment: This returns all vehicles not the vehicles that form returns after search process. I need search result as paginated.

Comment: I can't see your updated code in your Controller, only in your View. But I suppose that doesn't matter, since you're appending it..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82132/discussion-between-tartar-and-ciccio).

Answer (score 0):

When there is no `condition` parameter in the query string or the values of this parameter is not one of there values: `or`, `and`, `no`. The `$vehicles` variables is not set in your code. The `compact` function ignore a variable instead of thrown errors when its is undefined before, which lead to the error in your view.

Quote from [PHP documetation](http://%20Any%20strings%20that%20are%20not%20set%20will%20simply%20be%20skipped.)

> Any strings that are not set will simply be skipped.

You need to modify your code a little, choose an default value to make sure that your `$vehicles` is always set before sending it to views.

```
if($condition == 'no'){
    $vehicles = Vehicle::with('brand','section','representive','buyer','seller','buyingPaymentType','sellingPaymentType')->where($option1, $actual_option1)->paginate(2);
    //return $vehicle;
} elseif ($condition == 'or'){
    $vehicles = Vehicle::with('brand','section','representive','buyer','seller','buyingPaymentType','sellingPaymentType')->where($option1, $actual_option1)->orWhere($option2, $actual_option2)->paginate(2);
} else {
    # default value
    $vehicles = Vehicle::with('brand','section','representive','buyer','seller','buyingPaymentType','sellingPaymentType')->where($option1, $actual_option1)->where($option2, $actual_option2)->paginate(2);
}
```

Comment: Default value fixes the pagination problem but it does not return the actual search result afer form processed processed.